# Am I solving this inequality correctly?

Tags: inequality

Say I have an inequality as such ($a,b$ and $c$ are all positive numbers)

$a > b \times c$

Now I need to move $c$ to the L.H.S and separate it from others so this inequality would become

$c < \frac{a}{b}$

Am I doing this right? Since I changed sides of $c$ I also changed the equality sign.

Comment: It depends on signs of $a,b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You can see that by writing this:
$$
a > bc\\
\frac{a}{b} > c
$$

#### Edit

Important assumption was that $b > 0$. If $b < 0$ that itself switches the inequality and then switching sides is a second flip (so it stays the same).

For example. When $a = 6, b = 2, c = 1$ we have:
$$
6 > 2\cdot 1\\
3 > 1\\
1 < 3
$$

But when  $a = 6, b = -2, c = 1$ we have:
$$
6 > -2\cdot 1\\
-3 \mathbf{<} 1\\
1 \mathbf{>} 3
$$

Answer (score 1):

$ a > (b)(c) \to \frac{a}{b} > c$.. If this is just a regular inequality, I'm not sure what the question is... There is no need to flip the sign of equality.
If it was the case of $a > (-b)(c)$, we would have $\frac{a}{b} < c$
Plug in arbitrary values to see this is the case.